# KnockoutJs mapping to view model complex property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new to knockout and trying what I thought would be a simple scenario, but its just not working. Neither of the two input's changes when the selection changes, and the select list does not initialise to the selectedFormat.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedFormat.id" />
<input type="text" data-bind="enable: selectedFormat.fields()[0].enabled" />

<select data-bind="options: formats, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedFormat" />
```

JS:

```
var data = {
    formats: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Format 1', fields: [
            { id: 1, enabled: true }, 
            ]}, 
        { id: 2, name: 'Format 2', fields: [
            { id: 1, enabled: false }, 
            ]}
        ], 
    selectedFormat: 
        { id: 2, name: 'Format 2', fields: [
            { id: 1, enabled: false }, 
            ]}
    }

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paulbau/ZnqNN/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there in your fiddle, all the parts are there they just need to be connect.

Te mapping plugin don't create automatically observables for properties which holding complexs object. So by default your `selectedFormat` won't be an observable after the mapping. Because you want to write `value: selectedFormat` it has to be it observable therefore you need a custom mapping configuration which makes  `selectedFormat` observable:

```
var mapping = {
    'selectedFormat': {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
        }
    }
}
```

If you definied a `create` function then you are responsible the mapping of its value so you need to call `ko.mapping.fromJS` inside the create function with `options.data` to map the values inside the `selectedFormat` also observable.

Then you need to tell `ko.mapping` to use your mapping config with:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

And now just need to change your bindings because `selectedFormat` will be an observable so you need to get its value with `selectedFormat()`:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedFormat().id" />
<input type="text" data-bind="enable: selectedFormat().fields()[0].enabled" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RYZaW/)

If you want the initial selection work, then your mapping needs to lookup the selected item by id instead of creating a new object:

```
var mapping = {
    'selectedFormat': {
        create: function(options) {
           var selected = ko.utils.arrayFirst(options.parent.formats(), 
               function(item){
                   return item.id() == options.data.id;
            }); 
            return ko.observable(selected);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bpW8D/)

Comment: Ok thanks, that's got the dependencies working. But the select list still does not initialise to what selectedFormat is initially set to, e.g. if I change my JSON data so selectedFormat = { id: 2, name: 'Format 2' }, the select list still loads with Format 1 selected.